# Slicing a pandas series using a list of float slices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas Series with a float64 index.

e.g.

```
s = pandas.Series([1,2,3,4,5], index=[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0])
```

but with 100,000s of rows.

I would like to pull back multiple slices into a single subsetted series. At the moment I am doing this by building a list of slices and then concatenating them

e.g.

```
intervals = [(1,2), (4,8)]
s2 = pandas.concat([s.ix[start:end] for start, end in intervals])
```

Where intervals will be a list that is generally around 10-20 entries.
However, this is *slow*. Infact this line takes up 62% of the whole execution time of my program, which is taking about 30 seconds on a small subset of my data (about 1/2,000 of the whole dataset).

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't `s.ix[start, end]` be `s.ix[[start, end]]`? And, you want to get 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0.5.0 or just 1, 2, 4, 8?

Comment: Oops, you're right that I got it wrong. Should be s.ix[start:end] or as to get 1,2,4,5 (index 1.0,2.0,4.0 and 5.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will require some clever `numpy` `array` broadcasting, to check, for each value in `index`, if the value is between each of the intervals in the `interval` list (open on both end, such that >=low_end and <=high_end):

```
In [158]:
import numpy as np
def f(a1, a2):
    return (((a1 - a2[:,:,np.newaxis])).prod(1)<=0).any(0)
In [159]:

f(s.index.values, np.array(intervals))
Out[159]:
array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [160]:

%timeit s.ix[f(s.index.values, np.array(intervals))]
1000 loops, best of 3: 212 µs per loop
In [161]:

%timeit s[f(s.index.values, np.array(intervals))]
10000 loops, best of 3: 177 µs per loop
In [162]:

%timeit pd.concat([s.ix[start: end] for start, end in intervals])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.64 ms per loop
```

result:

```
1    1
2    2
4    4
5    5
dtype: int64
```